# Unable to Connect to SQL Server on a Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

I have followed this article to help setup and configure SQL Server on a Azure VM and have a heck of time trying to figure out why I can't connect from my ASP.NET web app running a EC2 VM.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/#SSMS

I have tried tweaking the connection string different ways and of course get different messages. Here is the latest one I am focusing on.

'The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found'

Here is my connection string:

```
Server=tcp:XXXXXX.cloudapp.net;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXX;Database=XXX;trusted_connection=false; integrated security=false; encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

Port 1433 is open on the server and I can connect via my local SQL Server without any problems. Ideas why I wouldn't be able to connect from a web app? I verified domain access via nslookup.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you followed specify the Public VM endpoint should have port 57500 (publicly exposed) and mapped to 1433 internally.  Since you're connecting from AWS EC2, it would definitely be connecting over the internet and therefore using your public VM TCP Endpoint, so you'll need to specify the port explicitly in your connection string:

```
Server=XXXXXX.cloudapp.net,57500;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXX;Database=XXX;trusted_connection=false; integrated security=false; encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

(Note the syntax involves a comma as opposed to a colon port separator in connection strings).

The connection string example at the bottom of the instruction article you followed fails to specify that you need to specify the port to your instance.

Also, it is worth double-checking in Sql Server Configuration Manager that the server instance has a fixed port for TCP/IP and that TCP/IP is enabled; named instances by default will use dynamic ports, which are difficult to work with behind firewalls.  A good overview of general Sql Server ports behavior (1433 vs 1434, etc) is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Iheria. I read what you suggested and doubled checked everything, and I am still getting the 'The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found' error.

I tried to connect via SQL Manager from EC2 to Azure and no problem. 

Here is my latest connection string.


connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxx.cloudapp.net,57500;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Database=xxxx;trusted_connection=false;Integrated Security=false;Encrypt=true;Trusted_Connection=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;" databaseVersion="2008"

Comment: You might try simplifying your connection string down to the bare minimum:  "Server=XXXXX.cloudapp.net,57500;Database=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXX;" (note, including removing the tcp: prefix as well).

Answer (score 0):

A very commonly skipped step is to not enabling `TCP\IP` for your installed instance of `SQL Server`. Details are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/ways-to-connect-to-sql#manualtcp

The relevant portion is:

1. In `SQL Server Configuration Manager`, in the console pane, expand `SQL Server Network Configuration`.
2. In the console pane, click `Protocols for MSSQLSERVER` (the default instance name.) In the details pane, right-click `TCP` and click `Enable` if it is not already enabled.
3. In the console pane, click `SQL Server Services`. In the details pane, right-click `SQL Server` (instance name) (the default instance is `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER))`, and then click `Restart`, to stop and restart the instance of `SQL Server`.